# Display:flex is causing element to disappear in dialog box in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, oracle-apex

I have created an application using Oracle APEX. It is working fine in all browsers without any issues. Recently, I have noticed that in one of the model/dialog box page, HTML elements like input box, select list disappears when clicked on it and reappear when I move to next item. This is not happening in the MS Edge or IE. Also, this happens only If I open this page in a dialog box. It will work perfectly if I open it as a page.

Once I looked into this, I found that wrapper div has display as flex. If I remove or change it to block using console, it is working fine. Since for each item, oracle apex create a item wrapper, this property is coming as default. I can change it using custom css but I am curious as why this is happening. It was working perfectly some time back and suddenly it is behaving like this. I can reproduce the same issue on other computers as well.

Is it the issue with chrome or do I need to make any other changes?

Page open with display as flex:
[image: Page open with display as flex]

Changes display to block:
[image: Changes display to block]

Text box is visible now:
[image: Text box is visible now]

Comment: Seems like a width issue to me try adding width: 100%; or max-width: 100%; on the text field

Comment: I issue is created due to some other properties, so it will be helpful if you provide minimum code to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug with Google Chrome as suggested by Oracle APEX team. I will use the workaround for now and will wait for updates from Oracle APEX.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4490473/text-fields-in-a-modal-page-disappear-when-you-click-on-them

Thanks.